# Does anyone know of a todo-list app that can sync via USB between iOS and Mac?

Tags: macos, ios, applications, data-synchronization, reminders

I've been looking for a todo-list app that can sync directly (via local/tethered USB) between my MacBook Pro (currently running Mavericks, upgrading soon to Yosemite) and iPod Touch 5 (running iOS 8).

Apple's Reminders and Notes can only be synced via iCloud.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: is syncing via iCloud an option too?

Comment: What about your local Wi-Fi? Supposedly Things has that option.

Comment: I think you can sync almost every app via local drives when using symlinks?

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for something similar, and it has proven quite difficult to find options. Everything's moving to the cloud.

[Appigo's Todo app](http://www.appigo.com/todo-task-and-to-do-list.html) seems to allow local sync, but that may be limited to Wifi sync (with both devices on the same network). Still, even something like that (which at least does not involve a 3rd party server) is hard to find.

Omnifocus has a similar option that allows sync without a 3rd party server, but it requires you to run a webdav server on your mac (e.g. via server.app).

I'd love to hear of other options!

Answer (score 0):

Look for "Todoist" on App store.  Not entirely sure about the USB connection though.

Also not sure why you would want that?  Seems a monumental backward step in functionality to me.

Try google drive if you're running low on storage space? Or Dropbox? Both free and Google has 15gb storage

Comment: Is privacy a good enough reason?